# TFS 2018 - move subset contents to another server/domain

Tags: tfs

Looking for documentation about **moving only a subset** of contents from a TFS 2018 server in certain domain and hardware to another TFS 2018 server in another domain and hardware.

More Details :
It is possible to follow general instructions for migrating a tfs to another server/domain, but we need only a subset of the contents i.e. contents for specific team projects in the single default collection that we have. The existing documentation in microsoft docs relates only to all the contents as a whole. We'd thus also like to assess whats recommended : migrate all and delete relevant contents on target or migrate only relevant contents from source to destination. Contents include : code, work items, Build & Release, all history, etc...

Answer (score 0):

There's no way split individual projects out of a team project collection without resorting to third-party integration tools and suffering from a lot of pain.

The best solution is to clone the team project collection using the standard process, migrate it, then delete what you **don't** want.